# Is it ok to save as window property a reference to the ref object returned from useRef hook?

Tags: reactjs

In my React app I have a fixed navbar and a scrollable div. The scrollable div contains all the content of the app.

I want to scroll the view in some circostances, but if I use `window.scrollTo` it doesn't work as the scrollable element is that div. I came up with a solution that is to assign a reference with the `useRef` hook and store that reference as window property.
Then when I need it I simply do `window.ref?.current?.scrollTo` and I get the job done.

**Question is: is it ok to do so? Does it break any of the hooks rules? I'm aware of the existence of `forwardRef` but is it really necessary here?**

*Also notice that the element that triggers the scroll is not a direct child of that div, so I would have to use forwardRef many times.*

Comment: Would probably be better to use a React Context to store the ref value and provide it back out to the app. "Is it ok to save globals?" It could be if you know what you're doing, but this is generally considered anti-pattern and should be avoid if possible.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I checked docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext and both App and ThemedButton need to access `ThemeContext`. So if, like in my case, they are in different files how can I set `ThemeContext` containing a ref created inside App and pass it to ThemedButton (the child component)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html The React Context API isn't the same thing as React hooks, they solve for different use cases.